# Firebase in Spring Boot Java application - FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist

Tags: java, spring, firebase

I use Firebase in order to send Push messages to mobiles from Spring Boot backend (I use Maven):

```
public class FirebaseServiceImpl extends AbstractService implements FirebaseService {

public FirebaseServiceImpl() {
}

@Override
public void initFirebase() {
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp("my-project-id");
    logger.info("firebase service initialized in FirebaseServiceImpl#initFirebase");
}

public void sendFirebaseMessage() {
    try {
        String registrationToken = "1:7250343492:android:3679c552666668aa369f09"; // "YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN";

        // See documentation on defining a message payload.
        Message message = Message.builder().putData("score", "850").putData("time", "2:45").setToken(registrationToken).build();

        // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
        // registration token.
        String response;

        final FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.getInstance();
        response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance(app).send(message);
        System.out.println("Successfully sent message: " + response);
    } catch (FirebaseMessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

If I invoke the method **sendFirebaseMessage** I get the following error:

```
handle request error 'FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist. Available app names: my- 
project-id
```

Actually I dont know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
final FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.getInstance();
```

You initiate a new app and save it into `app`, but you don't provide any name so it fetches the default.
As the documentation (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/master/firebase-common/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp.java#L172) says:

```
      /**
   * Returns the default (first initialized) instance of the {@link FirebaseApp}.
   *
   * @throws IllegalStateException if the default app was not initialized.
   */
  @NonNull
  public static FirebaseApp getInstance() {
```

and also:

```
    /**
   * Returns the instance identified by the unique name, or throws if it does not exist.
   *
   * @param name represents the name of the {@link FirebaseApp} instance.
   * @throws IllegalStateException if the {@link FirebaseApp} was not initialized, either via {@link
   *     #initializeApp(Context, FirebaseOptions, String)}.
   */
  @NonNull
  public static FirebaseApp getInstance(@NonNull String name) {
```

So if you initiate an app with a certain name, i.e as you did:

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp("my-project-id");
```

You also need later to fetch it:

```
final FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.getInstance("my-project-id");
```